# How to fix "error creating WebGL context"?

Tags: firefox, three.js, webgl, chromium

I wanted to test **Three.js** for a new project and imported it together with some example code.
In **Firefox however the canvas with the three.js stuff doesn't show up and I get the error & warnings** that you can see beneath. I guess the warnings appear because the WebGL context was not created correctly in the first place however I don't know what would go wrong there.

I don't know what could be the problem as the code runs fine and without warnings/errors in Chrome.

Both browsers were tested on an openSuse machine if that could play a role.

Thanks you for any hints on what could be wrong here!

[image]

Comment: What version of FireFox is your machine running? It looks like it [was an issue with FF72](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1608933), but should be fixed from 73 onward.

Comment: The first error message says exactly what the problems is. Your GPU/Drive is blacklisted. Update your GPU drivers or find out how to ignore the blacklist (dangerous).

Comment: Thanks for the link, I will take a look there. Regarding the version of firefox I got the result "Mozilla Firefox 68.9.0esr" when running 'firefox -v'

Comment: As this is not a personal PC I don't think that updating the GPU drivers probably is a viable option. Why would ignoring the blacklist for a driver be dangerous though? Also why is the driver a problem here but not in chrome then?

Comment: It's best to report such issues directly to the browser vendor: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/

Comment: The blacklist exists because the browse vender found a bug in the driver that could allow a webpage to potentially break out of the browser and run arbitrary code. Turning it off means allowing pages access to those bugs. That's why it dangerous. Chrome and Firefox are run by different people and have different blacklists. One browser might have found a workaround for the bug. Or, the other browser might not have run into the bug yet.

Comment: Also, you can report the bug but they aren't going to help you unless you install the latest version. Above you said you're running 68. [The current version is 84](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/84.0/releasenotes/). And even if 84 doesn't work for you they'll want you to test [the nightly version](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/desktop/) before they'll find the bug report useful

Comment: I tested the same thing with version 84 as well as the nightly version (86), still the issue persists in both